# How to use XML Auto to get the format obtained by XML Path in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, sqlxml

I am using sql server 2012.

This is my query:

```
CREATE TABLE #XmlTestTable 
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    FirstName VARCHAR(20),
    LastName VARCHAR(20)
)
INSERT INTO #XmlTestTable (FirstName,LastName) VALUES
('John','Doe'),
('Jane','Doe'),
('Brian','Smith'),
('Your','Mom')

select  FirstName as "Name/@FN",LastName  as "Name/@LN" from #XmlTestTable for xml path('X'),root('Y')
```

It gives results like this:

```
<Y>
  <X>
    <Name FN="John" LN="Doe" />
  </X>
  <X>
    <Name FN="Jane" LN="Doe" />
  </X>
  <X>
    <Name FN="Brian" LN="Smith" />
  </X>
  <X>
    <Name FN="Your" LN="Mom" />
  </X>
</Y>
```

How can I obtain this format using `XML AUTO`

```
select  FirstName as "Name/@FN",LastName  as "Name/@LN" from #XmlTestTable for xml auto
```

generates this:

```
<_x0023_XmlTestTable Name_x002F__x0040_FN="John" Name_x002F__x0040_LN="Doe" />
<_x0023_XmlTestTable Name_x002F__x0040_FN="Jane" Name_x002F__x0040_LN="Doe" />
<_x0023_XmlTestTable Name_x002F__x0040_FN="Brian" Name_x002F__x0040_LN="Smith" />
<_x0023_XmlTestTable Name_x002F__x0040_FN="Your" Name_x002F__x0040_LN="Mom" />
```

And could anybody tell me why I get the sting like `_x002F__x0040_FN` in above format?

Comment: Look up the character codes x002F and x0040. What do you get? What's your conclusion?

Comment: `_x0023_`, `_x002F_`, and `_x0040_` appear to be escape sequences for `#`, `/`, and `@`, respectively, those being their respective ASCII codes represented in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    (
        select *
        from (select FirstName as FN, LastName as LN) as Name
        for xml auto, type
    )
from #XmlTestTable as X
for xml auto, root('Y')

---------------------------------
<Y>
  <X>
    <Name FN="John" LN="Doe" />
  </X>
  <X>
    <Name FN="Jane" LN="Doe" />
  </X>
  <X>
    <Name FN="Brian" LN="Smith" />
  </X>
  <X>
    <Name FN="Your" LN="Mom" />
  </X>
</Y>
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/4629)</kbd>**